# Has BCDEdit Changed between Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bcd, bcdedit

In Vista I got -displayorder to work with BCDEdit. But in Windows 7 I cannot change the display order.  The only BCDEdit command that works for me is -timout.

I have researched the topic, but the dearth of articles maybe a clue that something has changed between Vista and Windows 7.

I have never seen strikethough used in Technet before, does this indicate that BCDEdit commands are no longer supported?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx

Incidentally I have got the job done with a 3rd party BCD editor, but I am curious as to how to get BCDEdit working in Windows 7 (and 8).

Question 1: Has anything changed with BCDEdit (or is it just my error)

Question 2: Can you recommend a good article on BCDEdit?

Comment: Example of Error: 'The set command specified is not valid.'

Comment: I see no strike-through text on that Technet article. Can you show us the exact command you are trying to run?

Comment: My mistake. No strikethrough, the bottom box lines weren't rendering correctly on this monitor.  I will work on some examples tomorrow.

Comment: bcdedit /set description "Guy W8" # Works

bcdedit /set {current} "Guy W7" # Doesn't work  neither does substituting any of my GUIDs

Error: The set command specified is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using `bcdedit` with PowerShell. Try running the same command with `cmd` and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried CMD too.